# multinomial distribution for unequal groups?

Tags: probability, multinomial-theorem

I am struggling to find a solution to this real life situation:
-Given 4 groups A B C D, with different probabilities of an outcome Z (pAz pBz pCz pDz)
-given that the number of people in each group is unequal
- the probability of the outcome in different people is independent 
what is the overall probability of the outcome Z (overall means among all groups, among all people)?
If only one group was present, I could easily solve it with binomial distribution or combinations. Given that there are 4 groups with different probabilities and unequal number of participants, what should I use?
Should I use multinomial distribution?

Edit: there is no process to select people in each group, this is are given data
I'd like to know the overall possibility of outcome Z
ie:

- Group A 4 people, having probability of Z=0.03
     group B 3 people: probability of Z= 0.05
     group C 3 people: probability of Z= 0.07
     group D 4 people: probability of Z= 0.08

what is the probability of Z?
I think the solution should account for all possible combinations (taken 2 by 2, 3 by 3 and so on).
If there was only one group, i could simply sum the binomial distributions.

edit2: trying to explain better with an example. There is only 1 suite in the hotel. People

- from city A will want it in 3% of cases
- from city B in 5% of cases
- from city C in 7% of cases
- from city D in 8% of cases

Given that tomorrow are going to arrive 4 people from A, 3 from B, 3 from C, 4 from D. What chances are the suite is used?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What outcomes are you looking at? Is there a process of selecting groups and/or people involved? Please clarify!

Comment: I have added information to clarify the post. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Can you pretend you're trying to explain this to a child. I'm having a hard time following.

Comment: I have now added an example to further clarify